# SQL: Search the text that contains in arrays

Tags: sql-server, arrays, t-sql

I have one select query for search, my @SearchText can be composed of a few words

I want to separate the words into an array and select if some text contains my search text

Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoreProcedure]
@SearchText varchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM t0 
        WHERE 
ISNULL(@SearchText, '')='' OR t0.title LIKE '%' +@SearchText + '%')
```

Now I want:
 if I search string 'adam smith' or 'smith adam' result must be the same

How I can to convert my **@SearchText** into array and extract rows from table-**t0** where title contains my @SearchText in any order

Comment: SQL does not have "arrays". SQL has tables with rows. So you'd want to take apart your `@SearchText` and put each word into a separate row of a temporary table, then search some database column's values for any combination of this temp table's contents. That being said, you'd probably be better off using SQL Server's full-text search capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I transmit parameter is need to delete double spaces and add between words "OR" like this:

```
searchText = searchText.Replace("  ", " ").Replace(" ", " OR ");
command.Parameters.Add("@SearchText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = searchText;
```

In SQL :

```
((@SearchText = '""') OR CONTAINS(t0.title, @SearchText))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using CONTAINS operator:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoreProcedure]
@SearchText varchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM t0 
        WHERE 
ISNULL(@SearchText, '')='' OR CONTAINS(t0.title,@SearchText)
```

More generic search you can do with [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) operator.

Comment: using contains is need to split word with 'OR' to work correctly